# Best Approach to read data from multiple tables

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, design-patterns

I have to create an Application to read some live data feed from more than 200 tables simultaneously and process this data. I want to discuss what could be the best approach to solve this problem with optimum speed as for each table we are getting 20+ records in every minute. So far I can think of following solutions :-

1) I can make multiple thread handling some 20 odd symbols independently.

2) I can make two thread one for data read and other for data processing but reader thread will take more time as it has to read all tables sequentially.

my database is MySQL and I am not looking to shift to nosql DB right now.I am using C++ to solve this problem.I feel that if instead of 200+ tables I can get live data feed in a single table then my second approach will become much appropriate and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Is the use of MySQL required if not you might get a speed increase from any nosql "database". Furthermore retrieving data from a database is always a bottleneck, generally when it comes to that much data volume you want to load as much as you can into RAM and read it from there, as it is much faster.

You could make a query that would only retrieve the newest data from a certain timestamp(which is the same timestamp of the execution of your last query) then load that into memory do all the operations that require speed there, and clean up old entries that are not required anymore.

Comment: thanks for your response , I have to use MYSQL , and quite  obviously I will always read the newest data only.